# Position Static Block under Category Grid

Tags: category, static-block

I have 3 categories set up to display Static Block & Products however I would like the static block to be displayed under the category grid. As this is not for every category only a few is there a way to achieve this  either using the Custom Layout Update tab or similar solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new yes/no attribute for the category names 'Show block below grid' with code `block_below_grid`. [See here how](http://indianicorange.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/how-to-add-custom-fieldattribute-in-magento-category/) (or search the web - this is common)
Now edit `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/catalog/category/view.phtml` and replace this :

```
<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php if ($_category->getBlockBelowGrid()) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
```

Comment: Please explain. How is this code an answer to the question?