# Category Grid View before Static Block

Tags: magento-enterprise

Hi I want to reposition the static block that I set on Display Setting under a specific category. I want the static block below the category grid view.

This is my code

```
<layout>
  <CATEGORY_49>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar" >
        <action method="setData"><data>_current_grid_mode</data><mode>grid</mode></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><count>5</count></action>
    </reference>
  </CATEGORY_49>
</layout>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer guys. Just want to share it

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="cms/block" name="Get started today with Office 365" after="-">
   <action method="setBlockId"><id>microsoft_office_365</id></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Please mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that from the layout.
You need to edit the `catalog/category/view.phtml` file.
Replace

```
<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
```

with

```
<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
```

But this will change it for all the categories.
If you want for a single category, read this: [Position Static Block under Category Grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/9344/146)

Comment: Thanks Marius but I already answer my own question hehe through XML code also. :)

Comment: @AlyssaReyes. Ok that will work, but in that case you don't use the block you select in the `Display Settings` tab. But I guess it's ok.

Comment: oh I see. I'll try your code. But I need the content under the category listing ONLY IN GRID VIEW. Is that possible on your code?

Comment: With the code I provided is not possible, but you can read the view mode I think and change the code I provided based on the value of the view mode.